# My User control belonging to which Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am creating a reusable component in C#.net.
For that i have started a Control Library project and added a Control.

```
Class MyControl : Control{}
```

My user control just displays some images which will be used in many Windows Applications.

Can you please tell me which design pattern i am using here.
I am unable to decide which pattern they belongs.

Thanks

Added:- 
What suppose for any problem my solution is to create a user control. Then i am following to which design pattern now????

See all the design pattern and lets deside.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: let's ask questions: i write "for" loop. what design pattern do i use?

Comment: @Andrey - "for", "if", "while", "foreach", "do-while" fall into the "loop" pattern

Comment: in what pattern? it is basic constructs of language. stop calling everything patterns.

Comment: i thought everything we are code followed any pattern may be we don't know what we followed?

Comment: @Andrey: language constructs can be patterns in a language that lacks the construct. There are some languages where almost everything you would call a pattern are implemented as a language construct. It is still useful sometimes to call them patterns, even if they are supported directly in some language.

Comment: no. it is not a pattern. it is one of basic concepts of computability. every imperative languages have: sequential execution, branch and loop, or condition and jump.

Comment: wiki: "In software engineering, a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design."

Comment: @Andrey, I think I see the problem here. For languages that don't have a loop construct you could have a 'pattern' in loose terms for developing a loop. I wouldn't call it a design pattern, more a language pattern (if such a thing exists). For design patterns then I think your wikipedia quote is spot in and an loop clearly doesn't fall into that scope.

Comment: there are two meaningful terms: language construct and design pattern. the border between them is defined by language. in c# and most other mainstream languages LOOP is language construct. It should not be called pattern. Do not produce confusion in terminology.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that we could say that you are following any design pattern, it's just basic Inheritance from what you describe which is a OOP principle not a design pattern. The process should be to identify which design patterns solve your problem and then implement them. Trying to do it in reverse is unlikely to reveal a pattern or if it does then I'd suspect the implementation would only very loosely follow said pattern.

Comment: What suppose for any problem my solution is to create a user control.
Then i am following to which design pattern????

Comment: Creating a user control isn't a design pattern, it is a simple as that. Design patterns are normally about more abstract concepts such a the repository, the singleton, the factory which are applying best practice to particular problem spaces. There isn't a design pattern for everything you do as a developer, sorry. I also hate to say it but if you didn't set out to implement a specific pattern then you haven't implemented it, you've just been lucky or brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

It does not sound to me like you are using any particular design pattern. At best, you are writing reusable code, but I don't think that is a design pattern in it's own right.

Answer (score 2):

- inheritance & abstraction - OOP's features to have a re-usable component

Don't think there is any design pattern involved here...

HTH

Comment: Where do you see @prashant applying abstraction here?

Comment: Abstraction - control implementation itself & of showing images, unless I am missing something...

Comment: Firstly I'd like to thank you for making me think, I had to go back and review my understanding of abstraction here so that's a good thing indeed! I'd see the class 'Control' as the abstract class here and MyControl as the concrete implementation, hence my question. That said, you have an interesting point regarding the content of 'MyControl', i.e. the images. However that is very much a 'has a' rather than an 'is a' relationship and as such is composition not abstraction although the OP is indirectly taking advantage of abstraction when they add their MyControl to the Controls collection.

Comment: @Lazarus - point taken about the composition. I was thinking of the implementation of the images in the control as abstracted from the user - ie. there could be a simple picture box to render or a third party control to give more capabilities etc. So, while the consumer of the control might be providing a list of images to show, the control itself might be providing an abstraction on the display & manipulation of the image...